# Is "on one hand, on the other hand" a cliche?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, discourse-markers

> We should find a Way of long peace instead of living just for today.  On one hand, we have to prevent the community from coming apart and suffering the disasters caused by it, on the other hand, to find a way of long peace for the society.
>   <sub>(my own translation of a Chinese article)</sub>

An American friend told me that we should sift through more the original structure of the Chinese sentence in order to give a fluent translation. ALthough correct, it is awkard in English.The main problem, he says, is "on one hand..on the other hand".

This is really a big problem for me, because in the article I am going to translate, there are abundant "on one hand..on the other hand". I am aware that it comes from English. But now in Engish it has become a cliche? Whereas in Chinese we desperately need it to clarify the logic in our thinking.

It seems to me, "on the other hand", if used independently, is acceptable. But when being used together" with "on one hand", is actually boring and dull.

I donot know which phrase substitute perfectly for "on one hand..on the other hand".Please give me some advice.

Comment: If I may be a grammar nazi, it's _on the one hand_. Not _on one hand_. I know, it's not intuitive, but that's the idiom.
 http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8846/why-is-it-on-the-one-hand

Comment: There is indeed something clunky about your translation. Your first hand holds a complete sentence with both subject and finite verb, while your second hand holds nothing but a non-finite verb and no subject, nor any connection back to the first part other than by rote repetition of the text seen in the sentence anterior to that of the first hand.

Comment: Context might help for this, but the 'long peace' also makes it sound foreign to the English language. As I said though, context might help if *long peace* has already been defined in the source material and you are continuing the concept. If not, you might also try synonyms for 'long', such as enduring, or lasting.

Comment: Off topic (writing advice request).

Comment: @TaliaFord: On one hand, that question has answers that support both possibilities. On the other hand, pfft...nGrams says that 'on the one hand' is ten times more prevalent than 'on one hand'. Not incontrovertible, but 'on one hand' is still used some.

Answer (score 20):

I don't think most readers would bristle at a single instance of the phrase – it's not tremendously trite and cliché.

That said, the expression's *overuse* could be distracting to the reader. You said:

> in the article I am going to translate, there are abundant "on one hand .. on the other hand".

If that's the case, there may be times you could eliminate the expression altogether, and adjust the wording to convey the same meaning; for example:

> *We should find a Way of long peace instead of living just for today. We must prevent the community from coming apart and suffering the disasters caused by it, **while at the same time** we must find a way of long peace for the society*.
>
> *We should find a Way of long peace instead of living just for today. We must prevent the community from coming apart and suffering the disasters caused by it, **yet we must also** find a way of long peace for the society*.
>
> *We should find a Way of long peace instead of living just for today. **We must do two things**: prevent the community from coming apart and suffering the disasters caused by it, **while also** finding a way of long peace for the society.*
>
> *We should find a Way of long peace instead of living just for today. We must prevent the community from coming apart and suffering the disasters caused by it. **That said**, we must also find a way of long peace for the society*.

Any of those would suffice in place of *"on one hand .. on the other hand."*

In short, I don't think you should be ***afraid*** to use the expression; on the other hand, you don't want to use it so often that it becomes distracting and overused within the article itself.

By the way, it ***is*** acceptable to use *"on the other hand"* without an *"on [the] one hand"* preceding it, as I just did.

Answer (score 3):

***First***, you are under no obligation to reproduce the idiom, in its entirety, word for word. ***On the other hand***, you do need to avoid repeating yourself. ***Therefore***, use alternative words to add variety to your text ***while*** helping your readers follow a list of different ideas and concepts at the same time.

***Basically***, these handy expressions act like sign posts that inform the reader what the next paragraph is going to be about. Be it confirming or contrasting an opinion, as in the OP's excerpt. ***As a result***, the ideas should connect to one another and the writing flow more naturally.

These fixed expressions are called: *[linking words](http://aeo.sllf.qmul.ac.uk/Files/Linking%20Words/Linking%20LOB.html)*, [*connectors*](https://www.dlsweb.rmit.edu.au/lsu/content/4_writingskills/writing_tuts/linking_LL/sentence.html), and [*formal discourse markers*](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/al/learning_english/leap/grammar/discourse/). They will help connect sentences and give them greater coherence. One word of caution though,  be careful not to overdo it (as I have) and use them sparingly to avoid  your writing sounding too heavy and artificial.

---

I'm not a writer, writing for me is difficult and if I had the time to refine and edit this paragraph, I would probably do a much better job. But I hope I have at least illustrated  how these expressions can be used as a tool, in your job as a translator.

***List of expressions for contrasting***

- However • nevertheless • nonetheless • still • although • even though • though
  • but • yet • despite • in spite of • instead • instead of
  • in contrast (to) • in comparison • while • whereas • on the other hand
  • on the contrary • conversely

***List of expressions for reinforcing and confirming***

- Similarly • likewise • also • just as • just like
  • similar to • same as • compare • compare(d) to/with
  • not only ... but also • notably • furthermore
  • moreover • obviously • particularly • especially • specifically

<sub>Source: [RMIT University](https://www.dlsweb.rmit.edu.au/lsu/content/4_writingskills/writing_tuts/linking_LL/linking3.html)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using the *on one hand . . . on the other hand* construction is that the two things being compared *must* have some sort of difficult problem of mutually exclusive conflict with each other, some kind of paradox or competing interest that is difficult or impossible to resolve.

The two abstract ideas presented here for contrast with each other don’t seem to be incompatible in any way.  If there is a conflict between them, you must tell the audience what that conflict is.  You would summarize the conflict after you explain what the problem is with an *on one hand . . . on the other hand* construction.

I think you cannot do this.  I think there is no actual conflict here.  You should probably just make a list:

> We need to do 2 things, X and Y.

Or just drop one of your concepts, because

> prevent the community from coming apart

and

> find a way of long peace for the society

are almost identical ideas.  No contrast exists between them.  One says *do not fight*, the other says *get along*.  It is as though you have said *do not **not** make peace* and attempted to contrast that with *make peace*.   Because the two negatives cancel each other out to make a positive, now both sides are saying the very same thing, and there is no contract.

Whatever distinction you’re trying to draw — if there indeed is one — you need to explain it better.

Comment: @tchrist what charset are you using? The ellipsis and some other weird char are not displaying as UTF8.

Comment: @mplungjan I am using UTF-8. Those are U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE characters separating each dot. Sometimes U+2009 THIN SPACE or U+200A HAIR SPACE are better, but they lack the “no-break” semantics. See [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105064/2085).

Comment: They do not work on either FX not Chrome on my windows box so I do not know where you get this from

Comment: @mplungjan you need to set your browser to use UTF8 or auto-detect encoding. In FX that's View=>Character Encoding.

Comment: I find it downright silly to change one char to a set of 6 chars just for the sake of a narrowspace. It adds nothing to the display and inconveniences a part of the visitors.

Answer (score 1):

*One one hand/on the other hand* is a well understood and much used idiom, but I see what you may mean. I do not personally see it as awkward at all

In the '80s a 3rd option was added and a lot of <s>nerds</s> SF lovers will understand "on the gripping hand" as such a reference

[image]

Your sentence would be syntactically correct as

> We have to prevent the community from coming apart and suffering the disasters caused by this and on the other hand find a way of long peace for the society.

Note I changed *it* to *this*

However I do not see the two as opposites so

> We have to prevent the community from coming apart and suffering the disasters caused by this, ***as well as*** find a way of long peace for the society.

Comment: You remind me of the logical connection between the two clauses. The Chinese article was wrong about it, I failed to notice it too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I see a downvote, that is not done here without comment!