# What is the grammatical name for these words?

Tags: adverbs

What is the grammatical category of the following words called: *perhaps*, *therefore*, *hence*, *nevertheless*, etc.?

Comment: Related: [Is “on one hand, on the other hand” a cliche?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129353/is-on-one-hand-on-the-other-hand-a-cliche)

Comment: @Mari-LouA No connection.

Comment: @NathanM. did you read the answers? And if you did, why is it not *related*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I read the answers and found nothing having to do with conjunctive adverbs...

Comment: @NathanM. … *linking words*, *connectors*, and *formal discourse markers*. ***They will help connect sentences*** *and give them greater coherence.*…

Comment: http://aeo.sllf.qmul.ac.uk/Files/Linking%20Words/Linking%20LOB.html

Comment: @Mari-LouA Still doesn’t answer this OP’s question or explain what conjunctive adverbs are and how they’re used.

Comment: @NathanM. perhaps you are unaware, but posting a related question does not imply that the answers offer the solution or the question being asked is identical. The OP didn't ask for the explanation of conjunctive adverbs, they asked how to classify the expressions they listed.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked these words in dictionaries, and they all list them as adverbs. In some cases they also list them as adverb and conjunction or "sentence connector".

As for the term "conjunctive adverb", it's true that they are commonly called that. Wikipedia has an article on this and they are listed there. But they're not necessarily in and of themselves conjunctions. For example, if a "conjunctive adverb" is:

> "...an adverb that connects two clauses..."
>  [Wikipedia
>   article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_adverb)

beginning a sentence with one of these words wouldn't be joining two clauses as clauses are usually defined as being within a sentence. If that's true, it's not acting as conjunction in any way. Also take the following examples:

> "He is sick and therefore not fit for duty".

If "and" is the conjunction, I doubt "therefore" is acting as another conjunction, but is merely modifying what follows as an adverb.

> "It is therefore imperative that we act now."
>  "It is however
>   possible that we arrested the wrong suspect."

In these last two examples "therefore" and "however' have no conjunctive role.

So I think it's most accurate to call them just adverbs, but which also act as conjunctions based on how they are used.

I think if these words were necessarily adverbs AND conjunctions more dictionaries would list them as conjunctions also instead of merely "adverbs".

Sources: (note, The Free Dictionary usually has the entries from American Heritage Dictionary, Collins Dictionary and Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary)

Nevertheless
[Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nevertheless)
[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nevertheless)
[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nevertheless)
[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nevertheless?s=t)
[webster-dictionary.net](http://www.webster-dictionary.net/definition/nevertheless)

Therefore
[Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/therefore)
[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/therefore)
[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/therefore)
[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/therefore?s=t)
[webster-dictionary.net](http://www.webster-dictionary.net/definition/therefore)

Hence
[Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hence)
[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hence)
[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hence)
[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hence?s=t)
[webster-dictionary.net](http://www.webster-dictionary.net/definition/hence)

As was pointed out by Nathan M "perhaps" isn't a conjunction, as far as I know, and isn't listed in the Wikipedia article, whereas the others are.
[List of common English conjunctive adverbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_adverb#Common_English_conjunctive_adverbs)

Answer (score 0):

All the words you listed, except for “perhaps,” are called [conjunctive adverbs.](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/conjunctiveadverb.htm)

Comment: I edited your answer to provide the OP with a more thorough explanation of conjunctive adverbs.

Comment: And “perhaps” is not a conjunctive adverb; it is just a regular adverb, like “maybe.” So, you are right.

Comment: You may want to rethink the opening word "These." After all, the OP's list begins with *perhaps*.