# Is "By one side, ..., by the other side" a correct expression?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

I've come across the formulation *by one side*, *by other side* instead of *on the one hand/side* and *on the other hand/side*. I strongly suspect this to be wrong and maybe Brazilian Portuguese originated, can you please confirm? (I only know the author comes from Rio, I don't speak Brazilian Portuguese).

Comment: It is not an idiom I'm familiar with in English. It does sound like a translation.

Comment: Yeah, it's not "familiar".  I believe I've heard similar formulations a few times, though.  Nothing really "wrong" with it, but it's not a common usage, and thus sounds a bit awkward.

Comment: Italian has the same expression "da un lato" = on one side. The appropriate English discourse marker is the one suggested by tchrist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not grammatical in English.  They are inappropriate word-for-word translations of the common Portuguese phrases *por um lado* and *por outro lado*.

In idiomatic English they should respectively be *on one hand* and *on the other hand*.

The principal error derives from the Iberian habit of omitting determiners in front of their words for “other”, and the translator not realizing that.  The secondary error is literally translating *side* where in English we use *hand* in the corresponding constructions.

Comment: Thanks! Btw., see the related question [Why is it “on *the* one hand”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8846/why-is-it-on-the-one-hand)